# How to apply opacity in the top of scrollview that have camera as parent SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui

I have a scrollview inside a camera view and I need to apply opacity in the top of scrollview

Actual / Expected behavior

[image][image]

I already tried it without success.

```
var body: some View {
    ZStack(alignment: .top) {
        VStack {
            
        }
        .frame(
            minWidth: 0,
            maxWidth: .infinity,
            minHeight: 0,
            maxHeight: 10
        )
        .opacity(0.5)
        
        ScrollView(.vertical, showsIndicators: false) {
            ScrollViewReader { scrollView in
                VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 16) {
                    ForEach(messages) { message in
                        LazyVStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 4) {
                            Text("\(message.sender)")
                                .kerning(0.02)
                                .fontWeight(/*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/.bold/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/)
                                .font(.system(size: 13))
                                .lineSpacing(21)
                                .foregroundColor(Color.white)
                            Text("\(message.text)")
                                .kerning(0.02)
                                .fontWeight(.medium)
                                .font(.system(size: 13))
                                .lineSpacing(21)
                                .foregroundColor(Color.white)
                        }
                    }
                }
                .onChange(of: messages) { _ in
                    scrollView.scrollTo(messages.count + 1, anchor: .bottom)
                }
                .onAppear {
                    scrollView.scrollTo(messages.count, anchor: .bottom)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

How can I apply opacity at top of this scrollview?

Comment: Does this answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/a/63874117/12299030?

Comment: I've tried this too, no success

Comment: It is a special case for you, as you do not have a defined background color (you have a video). So you basically have to use a mask. I did an example, however this will deactivatate Scrolling behavior which is still a bug in SwiftUI

Comment: davidev so there's no way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this issue with the following code

```
func getNameOpacity(_ distance: CGFloat) -> Double {
    return distance < 3 ? 1 : distance < 5 ? 0.7 : distance < 7 ? 0.5 : distance < 9 ? 0.3 : 0
}

func getTextOpacity(_ distance: CGFloat) -> Double {
    return distance < 23 ? 1 : distance < 25 ? 0.7 : distance < 27 ? 0.5 : distance < 29 ? 0.3 : 0
}

var body: some View {
    GeometryReader { outsideProxy in
        ScrollView(.vertical, showsIndicators: false) {
            ScrollViewReader { scrollView in
                VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 16) {
                    ForEach(messages) { message in
                        GeometryReader { insideProxy in
                            let distanceFromTop = outsideProxy.frame(in: .global).minY - insideProxy.frame(in: .global).minY + 6
                            let nameOpacity = getNameOpacity(distanceFromTop)
                            let textOpacity = getTextOpacity(distanceFromTop)
                            
                            VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 4) {
                                Text("\(message.sender)")
                                    .kerning(0.02)
                                    .fontWeight(.bold)
                                    .font(.system(size: 13))
                                    .lineSpacing(21)
                                    .foregroundColor(Color.white)
                                    .opacity(nameOpacity)
                                Text("\(message.text)")
                                    .kerning(0.02)
                                    .fontWeight(.medium)
                                    .font(.system(size: 13))
                                    .lineSpacing(21)
                                    .foregroundColor(Color.white)
                                    .opacity(textOpacity)
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    .frame(width: 100, height: 35, alignment: .center)
                }
                .onChange(of: messages) { _ in
                    scrollView.scrollTo(messages.count + 1, anchor: .bottom)
                }
                .onAppear {
                    scrollView.scrollTo(messages.count, anchor: .bottom)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```