# SwiftUI opacity gradient

Tags: swiftui

I am looking to have my scroll view fade out near the edge. I have implemented a mask, which almost achieves what I want. However, the scrolling stops working and the mask blacks out the rectangles (which should instead have images).

I have seen another post that overlays the background colour overtop of the view to create something that looks like a fade out, but my background is a gradient so it wouldn't work.

```
var body: some View {
    ZStack {
        LinearGradient(
            gradient: Gradient(colors: [Color(#colorLiteral(red: 0.1333333333, green: 0.7098039216, blue: 0.4509803922, alpha: 1)), Color(#colorLiteral(red: 0.1607843137, green: 0.6705882353, blue: 0.8862745098, alpha: 1))]),
            startPoint: .top, endPoint: .bottom)
            .ignoresSafeArea()
        
        LinearGradient(gradient: Gradient(colors: [.clear, .black, .clear]), startPoint: .leading, endPoint: .trailing)
            .mask(ScrollingRectangles())
    }
}
```

Here is the result of the above code:

[image]

Below is an example I threw together to illustrate what I'm trying to achieve.

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/a/63874117/12299030?

Comment: @Asperi This method is creating a white gradient overlay. My guess is that systemBackground is white by default?

Comment: why you do not use color: .clear?

Comment: @Omid The method linked is already overlaying a gradient that goes from clear to background (which appears as white), so if I did clear on the other end it would just all be clear.

Comment: Sorry, it goes from clear to systemBackground (which appears as white)

Comment: I think you are wrong, unless I did not get what you want! but you could have that same effect without withe color

Comment: @Omid This is what it looks like when I implement the answer from the other post: https://imgur.com/a/VRvIjBy It seems it would work well if my background was also white, but it is not. I have updated my answer to hopefully be clearer and added what I implemented that was closest to achieving what I want—it allowed for my view to truly fade to transparent at the edges (and maybe what you were suggesting, Omid). However, it no longer scrolls and the mask makes the shapes a solid colour, blocking out the images they will contain.

Answer (score 30):

You can check out this: https://designcode.io/swiftui-handbook-mask-and-transparency

OR

You can use `masking` to implement the transparency effect

```
ZStack {
    // Your View here....    
}
.mask(LinearGradient(gradient: Gradient(colors: [.black, .black, .black, .clear]), startPoint: .bottom, endPoint: .top))
```

Comment: Note the more colours you add before the clear make the fade smaller and small, and visa versa