# Fade in/out ScrollView Swift UI

Tags: swift, swiftui

Is it possible to fade in/out text at top and bottom of scrollview as users scrolls text? Xcode 14.2, iOS 16, Swift 5.7

I have research other solutions such as this: [SwiftUI - fade out a ScrollView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63873033/swiftui-fade-out-a-scrollview)

I have tried the following, but it is fading out the side horizontally and adding color. I want it to be vertical and transparent fade as in the picture.

```swift
ScrollView {
    ScrollViewReader { scrollViewProxy in
        VStack {        
            ForEach(chatMessages, id: \.id) { message in
                messageView(message: message)
                
            }
            .mask(
                VStack(spacing: 0) {
                    
                    // Top gradient
                    LinearGradient(gradient:
                                    Gradient(
                                        colors: [Color.black.opacity(0), Color.black]),
                                   startPoint: .leading, endPoint: .trailing
                    )
                    .frame(width: 250)
                    
                    // Middle
                    Rectangle().fill(Color.black)
                    
                    // Bottom gradient
                    LinearGradient(gradient:
                                    Gradient(
                                        colors: [Color.black, Color.black.opacity(0)]),
                                   startPoint: .leading, endPoint: .trailing
                    )
                    .frame(width: 250)
                }
            )   
        }
    }
}
```

I have used this code to produce a horizontal fade, but need vertical on both top and bottom. Here is what is in simulator now.

[image]

See image:

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This can be achieved using a `Rectangle()` mask with the top and bottom "removed" using a `.blendMode(.destinationOut)`

This allows you to have a fixed height gradient at the top and bottom.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var nameTextField: String = ""
        
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            Text("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.\n\nLorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.\n\nLorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.\n\nLorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.\n\nLorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.\n\n").bold()
        }
        .mask {
            Rectangle()
                .overlay(alignment: .top) {
                    ScrollMask(isTop: true)
                }
                .overlay(alignment: .bottom) {
                    ScrollMask(isTop: false)
                }
        }
        .padding()
        .foregroundColor(.white)
        .scrollContentBackground(.hidden)
        .background {
            Image("wave")
        }
    }
}

struct ScrollMask: View {
    let isTop: Bool

    var body: some View {
        LinearGradient(colors: [.black, .clear], startPoint: UnitPoint(x: 0.5, y: isTop ? 0 : 1), endPoint: UnitPoint(x: 0.5, y: isTop ? 1 : 0))
            .frame(height: 150)
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
            .blendMode(.destinationOut)
    }
}
```

[image]

An alternative way would be to use a single `LinearGradient` with multiple Colors/Stops. In this cases the top third fades in, and the bottom third fades out:

```
.mask {
    LinearGradient(colors: [.clear, .black, .black, .clear],
                   startPoint: UnitPoint(x: 0.5, y: 0), endPoint: UnitPoint(x: 0.5, y: 1))
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
}
```

See [here](https://www.fivestars.blog/articles/reverse-masks-how-to/) for more info on reverse masks